# ButtonField in a GridView setting ButtonType to "image" raise two http post (IE only)

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, postback, buttonfield

I am facing same problem as mentioned [**here**](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/104617/double-postback-using-buttonfield).

When using a ButtonField in a GridView and setting ButtonType to "image",on click it makes 2 http post. For these multiple postbacks on one click, the value of Postback is 'false' for the first time and 'true' for second time. If the button type is link or simple button, it behaves normally.

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"
 CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="../images/Delete.gif" ></asp:ButtonField>
```

Microsoft says its a known issue and has not been fixed yet, the way to address this is to use a template field which is a good solution for most cases, **but for my case I cant use template fields and the button has to be of image type**.
Is there any other way I can address this problem ?

**Update** : IE6,7,8 all versions share same problem. If there is some workaround, please post.

**Update2** : The value of 'Request.HttpMethod' is always 'POST' even if the two postbacks have different value for IsPostback. Checking for this can be one possible fix but it will have to be done on each page the a grid is used with ButtonField column in the scenario described above. Any ideas better than this one ?

Comment: I also tried the 'asp:CommandField' same results :( .

Comment: Is your problem also limited to just IE6?

Comment: yes, IE6,7,8 all have problems

Answer (score 0):

As said in the http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/104617/double-postback-using-buttonfield

you can change the button field to image button

Comment: ??? Afaik, this is a known issue and the solution is to use template field which I cant use as I stated in the op.